# How to check if a registry directory exists in C#, if not exists then do this-

Tags: c#

I have been trying to add a functionality in my software. Basically if my software is started, I want it to check if Visual C++ Runtime is installed in the PC. If not then **MessageBox.Show**("C++ Runtime doesn't exist. Please download it before continuing")

I am not very familiar with C# that makes changes to registry. The directory of the Runtime is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86.`

So basically if `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86` doesn't exist then show the message box.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are sir:

```
try
{
    RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86 ");
    if(rk == null)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Something doesn't exists");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     // your exception handling process
}
```

You have to include:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

Comment: `OpenSubKey()` can throw some exceptions. I wouldn't recommend it outside a try/catch, unless you are 100% sure about it

Comment: You are right, I edited my code.

Comment: Thanks alot! You are really helpful! :)

Comment: @ThunderModsYT If this answer helped you then please make sure to mark this answer as correct. (the tick at the left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Registry.GetValue(String, String, Object)`

API Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7

Remember to import Microsoft.Win32